# Trouble with installing python 2.7.12 on CentOS 6.8- adding path

Tags: python, centos

**Edited**
I tried to install Python 2.7 on my OS. 
I used the commenand :

```
yum install -y python27
```

here is the output :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.hosteurope.de
 * epel: repo.fedoralinux.ir
 * extras: ftp.hosteurope.de
 * updates: ftp.hosteurope.de
Package python27-1.1-25.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So it seems that it's done.But I still see previous version 2.6. Which address I should add to path in `.bashrc` file
it is at :

```
/opt/rh/python27/root/lib/modules
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/moduleobject.h
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/sysmodule.h
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/allmodules.py
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/allmodules.pyc
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/allmodules.pyo
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autosummary/templates/autosummary/module.rst
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/pm-utils/module.d
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/modulefinder.py
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/modulefinder.pyc
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/modulefinder.pyo
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisectmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collectionsmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_cryptmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functoolsmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_localemodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_multibytecodecmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_randommodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/arraymodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/cmathmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/dlmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntlmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/gdbmmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/grpmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertoolsmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmapmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/nismodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/parsermodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/selectmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/spwdmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/stropmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/timemodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/timingmodule.so
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlibmodule.so
```

Thanks for any comment or guide.

Comment: Did you run `./configure` first?

Comment: @cdarke yes of course.

Comment: I used this [link](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
. /opt/rh/python27/enable
```

Then ask for python version:

```
python -V
```

it outputs:

> Python 2.7.8

Now be careful, this is going to work as long as you keep your session. I.E. : as soon as you exit your shell, your environment variables are gone.

Comment: Actually, I wipe CentOS out and installed Mint, then I installed everything in a twinkle :)

Answer (score 0):

usually for more information about compile there is a file in your source directory like "config.log" that register all commands run during compile and errors

the command that do not allow you to complete make command is in this log file

you can see error and commands that give you error in this and search about it